# Is weight painting usually this unresponsive?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

Video References: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/Ea3o8-e2xiFFiAsTSlnh2hUBxFOzgj1XPCQQ5TM4rjRssg?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=X0SZrL

[image]

It is almost like I can't paint on certain area

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try pressing F and draging to make your brush larger. Weight painting only responds when the brush circle touches a vertex on the model you're painting. Also when you right click in weight paint mode you can change the strength of your brush 1= red 0=blue. I know that's kind of basic, but it's best to start simple

Comment: To see the vertices better enable the [Wireframe overlay](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#geometry).